View search results impersonating another user in SharePoint Subscription Edition
I am looking for a way to (even programmatically) impersonate users in my SharePoint Subscription Edition farm, and view search results on their behalf with their permissions, not my own elevated permissions.
I can run in the context of a farm admin to do so if needed.
What is the best way to achieve this? I don't mind using some PowerShell and .NET if needed.

You could ask bing copilot for the help..

Impersonating users in SharePoint Subscription Edition involves using the SPUserToken object. Here are the general steps:

Obtain the User Token: You need to get the SPUserToken object, which can be accessed via the UserToken property of the SPUser object.
Impersonate the User: Use the obtained token to impersonate the user.

Here's a basic example in C#:
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
    SPUser user = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("domain\\username");
    SPUserToken userToken = user.UserToken;

    using (SPSite impersonatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID, userToken))
    {
        // Perform actions as the impersonated user
    }
}

Make sure the account running this code has the necessary permissions to impersonate other users.
Source:
(1) Impersonation and Elevation of Privilege - Paul Schaeflein. https://www.schaeflein.net/impersonation-and-elevation-of-privilege/.
(2) How to Programmatically Impersonate Users in SharePoint. https://blackninjasoft.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint.
(3) Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint Servers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-server-2016.
(4) SharePoint Service Account Best Practices 2019/2016 - Microsoft Geeks. https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2019-service-accounts-best-practice/.
(5) Plan outgoing email for a SharePoint Server farm. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-planning.
